# MySQL and Infinispan - JTA implementation

Tags: spring, hibernate, infinispan, atomikos

We have an web application under Tomcat, integrated with Hibernate 4X, Spring 4X and HibernateTransactionManager as our transaction manager (currently one MySQL resource).

As part of our configuration distribution, we should integrate with **Infinispan** as our cache manager to store configuration **with other format than in the MySQL**. Meaning, **not** as Hibernate second level cache integration!

I managed to integrate Infinispan with Spring but now I'm facing a big problem due to the fact the MySql transaction and Infinispan **must be on the same @Transactional**.

I read about Spring JTA and how to integrate with Atomikos (e.g.) as our Global Transaction manager but I'm not sure if we can combine the whole entities to work together and how :(

I need to know if there's an option to work with Atomikos Spring JTA so the Infinispan will recognize this JTA implementation and will handle the **MySql and Infinispan as one global transaction! (2PC)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would suggest to configure Spring + Hibernate + JTA together. Here is a very nice [tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/). If you configured everything correctly - you should have one bean of a type `TransactionManager`. In above tutorial it is configured inside this block:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public TransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
  UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
  userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
  return userTransactionManager;
}
```

Now you may [configure Infinispan to use this transaction manager](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_transactions). The easiest way to achieve this, is to implement your own [TransactionManagerLookup](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/transaction/lookup/TransactionManagerLookup.html). This should return the transaction manager, which was created above.

Finally you have to create transactional cache, like this:

```
<local-cache name="transactional">
    <transaction mode="FULL_XA"/>
</local-cache>
```

After that everything should work with the same Transaction Manager and Spring should handle everything within single `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Just a very small observation - since you require Hibernate and JTA (for transactions), maybe it's worth to go for Wildfly application server instead of Tomcat + Atomikos?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Unfortunately, I managed to do the same as you wrote and forgot to update my question :(  
Now I have biggest problem, due to some limitations and bugs we found in Infinispan, my requirement now is to do it with Redis, which not supporting XA (for my understanding).  
  
Do you have any idea ?