# Spring Boot Tests within a Container

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, jboss-arquillian, infinispan

I have coded a Spring Boot based web application, which is expected to be run in WildFly server. The applications runs great, but the issue is with testing.

I have the database connections, caching and transaction management dealt by the server. Now, I need to be able to test them. While I was able to get through database connection problem through a mock JNDI connection and the transaction management, I'm not sure how to deal with testing of the caching.

One solution is to use Arquillian project. But, either this project is unable to recognize Spring Boot/ I'm doing something wrong, which is causing me pain to test the application.

Can someone please suggest on solving the issue? Below are my hibernate specific properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager=java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=infinispan
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.infinispan.cachemanager_jndiname=java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Based on the [docs](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_jpa_hibernate_second_level_cache_provider), InfinispanRegionProvider shouldn't need JNDI, but the directory provider for Hibernate Search probably does need it.

Comment: The error is with getting around the transaction manager lookup class.. "Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: This is transactional cache but no transaction manager could be found. Configure the transaction manager lookup properly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a separate configuration for tests. This configuration would contain a definition of a TransactionManager bean - [here is an example from other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700949/mysql-and-infinispan-jta-implementation/28027789#28027789). The next step is to provide your own implementation of [TransactionManagerLookup](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/transaction/lookup/TransactionManagerLookup.html) and applying it to Transport configuration - as described in [the manual](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_transactions).